# Как программно прочитать переменную окружения linux

Tags: linux, c, unix

Пишу программу на C для linux, возможно ли программно считать значение определённой переменной окружения?

Comment: Функция [getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv). \ Зачем метка bash?

Comment: Они могут передаваться в `main` как последний аргумент с типом `char * *`.

Comment: Спасибо, просто эти переменные обычно в bash используются.

Comment: вы не поверите: «эти переменные» «обычно используются» во **всех** программах (правда не всегда явно). и, кстати, в подавляющем большинстве операционных систем (пишу «в подавляющем большинстве» вместо «во всех» ввиду того, что, может быть, и существует какая-нибудь эзотерическая операционная система, в которой «эти переменные» не используются, но я о такой не слыхал).

Comment: Например, `char *home = getenv("HOME"); printf("HOME = '%s'\n", home ? home : "???");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно прочитать значение переменной окружения в linux можно с помощью функции [getenv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *name = "PATH";
    const char *env_p = getenv(name);
    if (env_p) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", name, env_p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Возможный вывод

```bash
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```